# Googlemap Marker - Image Fade

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to access the image object of a googlemap marker. Does anyone know where it exists in the marker object?

Regards,
Ash

EDIT: I'm asking for the HTML DOM Image object, not the MarkerImage object.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to access the image object directly from the marker object.
What makes it hard to access the image objects is that Google Maps V3 does not assign ids to the divs the enclose the img elements.

However, it is possible to dig through the DOM and find the individual divs that wrap img elements.
A marker can have multiple images associated with a single marker, including: the icon image for the marker, shadow, tooltip.
Each of these are in different divs in the map canvas div, for example the icon image is in a div with z-index = 103.

The problem remains of how to find individual markers. One way (not optimal) is to assign a zindex to the marker when creating the Marker.

If you are using jQuery, you can then select and fade the marker by using fadeOut or setting the opacity, e.g.

```
$('div[style^="z-index: 103;"] div[style*="z-index: 123"]').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

where 123 is the zindex you set on the marker.

Comment: I'm looking for those divs and I can't find them.  In fact, the first time that I tried, it worked, but I can't reproduce the situation!  I searched the whole DOM for z-index: 123 and found nothing.  Does your technique still work?

Comment: Another thought: Is it possible that it's being drawn directly to a canvas, without using "img" tags?

Comment: ARG!!!  Okay, z-index: 123 only works if you aren't using the drop animation.  The drop animation is done on a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

```
marker.getIcon()
```